# Convert openCV Rect coordinates into CGRect coordinates in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, opencv3.0, drawrectangle

I want to convert openCV rectangle coordinates into CGRect so I can draw image using this.

```
rectangle(frame, box, Scalar(0,0,255));
```

In the below code I create the rectangle with these parameters as frame is mat type ,box is CGRect type.

In openCV it display rectangle correctly but I need to create UIImage with same frame.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571274/ios-get-cgpoint-from-opencv-cvpoint) ?

Comment: Thanks for reply but I already checked this its not working. @NightFury

Comment: Now I solve this by copy the image with the help of rectangle frame and display this.